# Angular - ngFor change variable after click

Tags: angular, loops, variables, ngfor

So, lets assume i have this ngFor loop:

```
<ng-container*ngFor="let rate of [1,2,3,4,5]">
    <div (click)="change()">{{myVariable}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

I have variable 5 displayed times in my template, what I want to do is to change variable after clicking on it, that the one that was clicked and previous are changed and next ones stays as they were. 
When I have:

```
export class StarRatingComponent {
  myVariable = 'a';

  change() {
    this.myVariable = "b";
  }
}
```

If I click on `a` then all are changed to `b`. How to apply this change only for clicked item and previous ones? so for eg. from `aaaaa` to `bbbaa`?

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass the value of the selected rating.

Something like this could work:

```
<ng-container*ngFor="let rate of [1,2,3,4,5]">
  <div (click)="change(myVariable)">{{myVariable}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

Then in component, track those by index:

```
export class RatingCmp {
  rating: string = '1';
  change(rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
  }
}
```

Comment: Saddly, it doesn't work. + I know how to recive number of clicked item, so if someone clicks on third a I get "3", but don't know how to change this "a" to  "b", but thank you for your help and time.

Comment: In that case, we're missing info. What exactly do you want to change? You only have single 'a' on the component, fo course it's changed for all?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following approach:

```
<ng-container*ngFor="let value of values; index as i">
    <div (click)="change(i)">{{value}}</div>
</ng-container>

export class StarRatingComponent {
  values = this.generateValues('a',5);

  private generateValues(val: string, times: number): string[]{
    const result: string[] = [];
    while(--times >= 0){
       result.push(val);
    }
    return result;
  } 

  change(index: number) {
     while(index >= 0){
       this.values[index] = 'b';
       index--;
     }
  }
}
```